# android viewpager notifyDatachange return to first

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, tabview

I'm working in an android projet. I use tab to display data with fragment. In the third fragment, when i update data, viewPager return to the first. I try everything.

This is my viewPagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int baseId=0;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // give an ID different from position when position has been changed
        return baseId + position;
    }

    /**
     * Notify that the position of a fragment has been changed.
     * Create a new ID for each position to force recreation of the fragment
     * @param n number of items which have been changed
     */
    public void notifyChangeInPosition(int n) {
        // shift the ID returned by getItemId outside the range of all previous fragments
        baseId += getCount() + n;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38388010/5723796

Comment: I don't see any notify data change related code in your question. If you reload data in a fragment that own for exmple a listview it should not affect the viewpager

Comment: Why are you notifying `ViewPagerAdapter`? Update data in fragments seperately

Comment: It work finally. I when i change data, there is some code in activity that redraw viewpager. Thank a lot.